# WebMethod returning JSON but the response obj in my $.ajax() callback is only a string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here is my home-made Serializing class:

```
public class JsonBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder json;

    public JsonBuilder()
    {
        json = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public JsonBuilder AddObjectType(string className)
    {
        json.Append("\"" + className + "\": {");
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder Add(string key, string val)
    {
        json.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":\"{1}\",", key, val);
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder Add(string key, int val)
    {
        json.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":{1},", key, val);
        return this;
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        return json.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "}";
    }
}
```

Here is the Web Method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetPersonInfo(string pFirstName, string pLastName)
{
    var json = new JsonBuilder().AddObjectType("Person");
    json.Add("FirstName", "Psuedo" + pFirstName).Add("LastName", "Tally-" + pLastName);
    json.Add("Address", "5035 Macleay Rd SE").Add("City", "Salem");
    json.Add("State", "Oregon").Add("ZipCode", "97317").Add("Age", 99);
    return json.Serialize();
}
```

The Ajax call client-side

```
 $.ajax(
   {
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/GetPersonInfo",
       data: JSON.stringify(name),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (rsp) { SetPerson(rsp); },
       error: function (rsp)
       {
           alert(rsp);
       }
   });
```

And finally, my callback method

```
function SetPerson(rsp)
{
    $('#fName').val(rsp.d.FirstName);
    $('#lName').val(rsp.d.LastName);
    $('#address').val(rsp.d.Address);
    $('#city').val(rsp.d.City);
    $('#state').val(rsp.d.State);
    $('#zip').val(rsp.d.ZipCode);
    SetPerson(rsp.d.Age);
}
```

rsp.d is a string that contains all the properties ... the properties themselves are undefined. I know I am missing something simple here.

Returned string from server

```
"Person": {"FirstName":"Psuedomatt","LastName":"Tally-cox","Address":"5035 Macleay Rd SE","City":"Salem","State":"Oregon","ZipCode":"97317","Age":99}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the JSON string returned from the server looks like?

Comment: @Jeremy Battle updated the post to include the returned string

Comment: As an aside, i would look in to the [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) classes and save yourself a headache.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't manually serialize the return value; ASP.NET will do it for you.  Try something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Person GetPersonInfo(string pFirstName, string pLastName)
{
  // Assuming you have a server-side Person class.
  Person p = new Person();

  p.FirstName = "Pseudo" + pFirstName;
  p.LastName = "Tally-" + pLastName;
  p.Address = "5035 Macleay Rd SE";
  p.City = "Salem";
  p.State = "Oregon";
  p.ZipCode = "97317";

  // ASP.NET will automatically JSON serialize this, if you call it with
  //  the correct client-side form (which you appear to be doing).
  return p;
}
```

If you need to return something more dynamic, like your example seems to be doing, you can use an anonymous type:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object GetPersonInfo(string pFirstName, string pLastName)
{
  // ASP.NET will automatically JSON serialize this as well.
  return new {
    FirstName = "Pseudo" + pFirstName,
    LastName = "Tally-" + pLastName,
    Address = "5035 Macleay Rd SE",
    City = "Salem",
    State = "Oregon",
    ZipCode = "97317"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dave Ward This is helpful but not what I am after. I am experimenting with cases in which I don't want to have to create a class to represent the data server side.

Comment: See my edit for a more dynamic (though not actually "dynamic") approach.

Comment: @Dave Ward What version of asp.net does support for this begin at? We are using 3.5 with my company.

Comment: 3.5 supports all of that.  Anonymous types actually compile to statically typed classes under the hood.  They aren't the same as 4.0's `dynamic` type.

Comment: @Dave Ward This works perfect. But I am curious to what is going wrong with my approach. I have the dataType: "json" ... and I am following all of the required JSON grammar rules (I hope) ... why does it come back as a string?

Comment: Because the response is doubly serialized.  ASP.NET automatically JSON serializes the response. You're returning your manually built JSON string and then ASP.NET is using JavaScriptSerializer to transparently serialize your JSON as...  JSON.  So, when jQuery unwraps one level of JSON serialization, the data you returned it still a JSON string.  Basically, you should never manually JSON serialize the return from page methods and "Script Services".  JavaScriptSerializer works great on its own if you work with it.  It's just not obvious at first that it does that work for you automatically.

Comment: @Dave Ward aaahhhh that makes mucho sense. Thank you sir for the better approach and follow up! Up vote!!