# autocomplete textbox from the database

Tags: c#

I need my textbox to autocomplete when the user types. The value should come from the database.
I am using the textchange property of the textbox.

```
protected void autocomplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "Select area,codes from tbl_pincode";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=win2008-2;Initial       Catalog=h1tm11;User ID=sa;Password=#1cub3123*;Persist Security Info=True;");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        zipcode.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

But i m not getting the desired result.
Any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: Nice password: `#1cub3123*`. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET app, WPF, WinForms??? Please provide more information

Comment: You should wrap all 3 conn, com, and dr in `using` statements.

Comment: it is a simple asp.net c# code

Comment: @asifa please add the asp-net tag to your question

Comment: walah! he is giving a chance to hackers to get into the database systems...

Comment: Folks just because someone sent a password doesn't mean we need to reiterate it or make comments about hackers.  You should of done the right thing and edited the post - it would of been the right thing.  For all we know this could of been an internal sql server with no rights to the outside world - not easily hackable when its not on the network.  Come on folks.

Comment: What are the chances that such password is real? If it were me I'd just write `potato` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI for autocomplete: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

Another option for ASP.NET autocomplete is AjaxControlToolkit: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: I want the data to be filled from the datasource. I m using two columns of the db. The user can type the area or the postcode in the textbox and relative autocomplete options should be displayed.

Comment: I guess the first link gives you a good explanation on how to do that. To retrieve information, change the method FetchEmailList (and its name, of course) to make a call to your DB. Then, create an object to store the information and replace the Employee class from the article with this brand new object.

Comment: You can't do it without changing your method because the approach of the first article is different from yours. The article creates a service to return data to be consumed by jquery (javascript on client-side). Your code is using code-behind to change the html in the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using the jquery ui autocomplete component? You can hook this up to a remote datasource

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I want the data to be filled from the datasource. I m using two columns of the db. The user can type the area or the postcode in the textbox and relative autocomplete options should be displayed.

Comment: That is do-able as the component can be populated from a remote data source

Comment: can u plz tell me how to go about it?

Comment: The documentation on the jquery ui website is very good and you should probably start there. You will need to provide a service/endpoint that can supply the component with the data it needs in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Never put your connection strings on ANY forum
2. Use AJAX otherwise you'll have to postback the page every time the user types a character. JQuery & [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) provide easy support for autocomplete features.
3. use [Telerik RadCombo](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/combobox.aspx) (but you need to buy a license)

EDIT:

If you choose to use the JQueryUI autocomplete, I'd start from the [remote JSONP](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example.
You can point the `url` property of the `ajax` call inside the autocomplete's `source` function to a [WebMethod](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx) in your page. This will receive an object containing the filter (`data` in the example) and return the required values from your database in JSON format (e.g. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228648/webmethod-returning-json-but-the-response-obj-in-my-ajax-callback-is-only-a) example)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. How to write the source parameter in asp.net so that it can take the values from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all rows from the `tbl_pincode` table, not just those that match the character(s) the user has input. You are then assigning the value from the `area` column for each row to `zipcode.Text`.

Maybe try:

```
protected void autocomplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipcode.Text))
        return;

    string query = @"
        SELECT area FROM tbl_pincode WHERE area LIKE @Value
        UNION 
        SELECT codes FROM tbl_pincode WHERE codes LIKE @Value";

    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand com = null;
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=win2008-2;Initial       Catalog=h1tm11;User ID=sa;Password=#1cub3123*;Persist Security Info=True;");
        com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        string value = string.Format("{0}%", zipcode.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", value);
        conn.Open();
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            zipcode.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
        if (dr != null) dr.Dispose();
        if (com != null) com.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The SQL selects area and codes that start with the character(s) the user has input so far. which is what I think based on your comments to other answers. I've also change the `while` loop to and `if` block as I can see why you would want to assign and then re-assign values to the `zipcode.Text` property (I could understand if you were appending to a List control).

Comment: Hi thanks but the entire values from the db is printed in the textbox i want it to be displayed below the textbox and the user can select it just like a normal autocomplete. how to go about it?

Comment: Are you using a standard ASP.NET TextBox control? If so, I am not sure how you do auto complete for it or whether it supports auto complete. The only thing you can take away from my answer so far is the improved SQL statement.