# webmethod return values form base class

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

```
{"__type":"CountryModel","dt":null,"ds":null,"dtRow":null,"strSQL":{"Capacity":16,"MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Length":0},"iCnt":0,"ConnType":"FP","Code":"AE","Value":"United Arab Emirates"},{"__type":"CountryModel","dt":null,"ds":null,"dtRow":null,"strSQL":{"Capacity":16,"MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Length":0},"iCnt":0,"ConnType":"FP","Code":"AF","Value":"Afghanistan"},{"__type":"CountryModel","dt":null,"ds":null,"dtRow":null,"strSQL":{"Capacity":16,"MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Length":0},"iCnt":0,"ConnType":"FP","Code":"AG","Value":"Antigua and Barbuda"},
```

this is the webmethod that I return by json, but the problem is, asp.net return value from base class that I inherit from, how to solve this? although is working, but the data are wasted as I don't wish to return the value, any idea?

**BaseModel.cs**

```
   public string ConnType="";
   public datatable dt;
```

**CountryModel.cs:**

```
public class CountryModel:BaseModel{
   public List<MenuFunctionModel> AssignList()
{
    var _List = new List<MenuFunctionModel>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        _List.Add(new MenuFunctionModel
        {
            Code = dr["Code"].ToString(),
            Title = dr["Title"].ToString(),
            Description = dr["Description"].ToString(),
            Location = dr["Location"].ToString() + dr["FileName"].ToString()
        });
    }
    return _List;
}
}
```

**webservices api:**

```
    [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<CountryModel> loadCt()
{
    CountryModel _Country = new CountryModel();
    _Country.SelectAll();
    return _Country.AssignList();
}
```

Comment: do you want to return only a part of data of `MenuFunctionModel`?

Comment: yes, I just wanna to return the part that inside the List, but it seen like it return everything, due to to List<MenuFunctionModel>?

Comment: This is due to the return type (`List<CountryModel>`) you have used in webmethod. you can use another class that contains only required number of fields, or use anynomous type

Comment: any example link that I can refer to? or I change every base class public variable to private, but this will had more change impact to other classes as I plan to use all the variable as global

Comment: Should be the class that inherit to the base model that cause the problem, any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return anynomous types from your WebMethod as:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static Object loadCt()
{
    CountryModel _Country = new CountryModel();
    _Country.SelectAll();
    return _Country.AssignList().Select(m=> new{ Code=m.Code, Title =m.Title}); //select those fields only which you want to return
}
```

For more references, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228648/webmethod-returning-json-but-the-response-obj-in-my-ajax-callback-is-only-a)

Comment: always welcomed!. We all are thankful to this great community community for sure!